# Why the color of the image changed when it compressed by Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG

Tags: android, image-processing, compression

I am trying to compress the photo took by the camera in Android. But the color of the image changed when it compressed by Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

I have put some sample images which generated from my code. You can see the color of the paper on the top of the images is different.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.FOLDER_PATH + "pic.jpg");

FileOutputStream stream2 = new FileOutputStream(Common.FOLDER_PATH + "pic100.jpg");         
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream2); 

FileOutputStream stream3 = new FileOutputStream(Common.FOLDER_PATH + "pic100.png");         
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream3);
```

This is original image:
[image: original]

This is JPEG:
[image: jpg]

This is PNG:
[image: png]

Comment: Where is the color change? I can't see it with the naked eye. Is it just about JPEG compression artifacts?

Comment: The middle one is different from others. I can see the paper on the image is little bit green.

Answer (score 1):

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format and there may be loss of image information during the compression. The sacrifice of original image information is made for a better compression ratio (resulting in smaller file).

However, if this is not acceptable for you, you should use one of the lossless compression methods which includes the [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: Yes, JPEG is lossy compression. But Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG changes the color of the image. I do the same compression in Photoshop, the color remain the same. I wonder what have I missed in the code.